# Magento 2 data migration error ConfigurablePrices step mismatch of entities:catalog_product_entity_decimal

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I'm migrating data from M1 v1.8.0.0 to M2 v2.2.0, and receiving this error at the volume check for ConfigurablePrices:

> [2018-01-08 05:56:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
>   100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>   [2018-01-08 05:57:00][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
>   100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
>   [2018-01-08 05:57:00][ERROR]: **Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_decimal**

The mismatch is due to 23 records being added to the M2 catalog_product_entity_decimal table that isn't in the M1 table.

I don't understand where this is coming from. I've done more migrations process but every time I get this ERROR.

**Anyone has idea about this error?**